# How to achieve the following stream information using FFMPEG parameters?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding

```
  Duration: 00:52:37.26, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1329 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1210 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 90k tbn (default)

  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 112 kb/s (default)
```

EDIT:
Okay, so I want to convert a *.mp4 file into the formats for HLS (.m3u8 and .ts files)
My question is what are the FFmpeg parameters to achieve the stream information I posted above?

For the ACC audio stream, I know the parameter is `-c:a aac -ar 44100 -b:a 112k`

I hope you can help me with the video stream information. Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To get h264 encoding: `-c:v libx264`;
Specify framerate: `-r 24`;
Specify resolution: `-filter:v scale=1280:720`;
Specify an average bitrate: `-b:v 1211k`;